# Ros Launch File

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone describe, in detail, the parameters involved in the launch file. I combed through the tutorials and the descriptions are not that adequate?

Is there an example you can point me to as well that call 3 or more packages/nodes? The type and name parameters have me at a slight loss...

I am trying something like:

But with the <! commented lines added. I receive errors on rov_teleop and teleop_rov_joy saying no such type. If my package is named rov_telop (yeah i know i wasn;t paying attention when I named it) and two nodes that work with "joy" are teleop_rov_move and teleop_rov_joy, what would the proper type and names be? I've tried pkg="rov_telop" type="teleop_rov_move" name="teleop_rov_mov" but no go...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46113/ros-launch-file/) by [101010](https://answers.ros.org/users/3108/101010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2012-10-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-10-17**:
@101010 Can you elaborate on what are you trying to accomplish ? If you read a launch file completely then most of the issues are sorted out.

**Comment by [101010](https://answers.ros.org/users/3108/101010/) on 2012-10-18**:
Something along the lines of:

**Comment by [101010](https://answers.ros.org/users/3108/101010/) on 2012-10-18**:
Something along the lines of:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a number of launch files in ROS projects on Github.  That would likely be a great place to find some real-world examples to help you out:

[Github Launch File Search](https://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=roslaunch&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

---

Originally posted by [toddsampson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3403/toddsampson/) with karma: 36 on 2012-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can look at [this](http://ibotics.ucsd.edu/trac/stingray/wiki/ROSNodeTutorial) tutorial to see a simple example of several concepts, including the use of launch files for C++ and Python nodes with parameters (launch file links are near the end).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-10-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1